# Rotate uiimage instead of uiimageview. Showing borders of uiimageview same as before only changing image

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview, touches

I want to rotate the uiimage inside uiimageview using touches. But while rotating the image imagview borders should be not disturbed only image should be rotated. Anybody have idea how can i do that.I have seen many examples using gesture but i cannot use gesture recognizers since i have already written code for resizing uiimageview from corners using touches. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I would put the UIImageView into a UIView on which you handle the touches, and just apply the transform to the UIImageView. As long as the UIView doesn't clip the bounds it will show the entire UIImageView and you can let the interactions happen on the UIView. The borders would also be set on the UIView.

Rotating the UIImageView will then be as simple as:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(ANGLE_IN_RADIANS);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rotate the `UIImage` object alone by setting the property

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIImageOrientation imageOrientation
```

You can find the orientations here
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

As for making the image to change on touching without the use of gesture recognizers, I don't think it is possible. But, you can solve your multiple gesture recognizers on the same view by using methods like

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

available in UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol. I am pretty sure, you can specify which gestures should do what in your case, without changing the views and their heirarchy.

Comment: I assumed he wanted full control of the rotation angle, but this would work if he only needs the 4.

Comment: @PhilippeSabourin Thank you for pointing that out. If the image needs to be rotated in any angle, it should be put in a view and be done as in your answer.+1